# it stores --"name":null,"message":null.--- in database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io

I am creating a chat app using socketio and mongodb to store the user name and his chat messages.
When I hit on "send" button ,the console display "Inserted" and there is no problem in executing code but it stores null value in database.
my database name is:'user' and table name is :'info'.
please help. thns in advance.

```js
var app=require('express')();
var server=require('http').Server(app);
var io=require('socket.io')(server);
var path=require('path');
var fs=require('fs');
var mongo=require('mongoose');
var ObjectId=require('mongodb').ObjectID;

server.listen(3000);

var MongoClient=require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url='mongodb://localhost:27017/';

app.use(__dirname + '/public');
var mongo=require('mongodb').MongoClient;
 client=require('socket.io').sockets;

app.get('/',function(req,res){
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

MongoClient.connect(url,function(err,db){
 if(err)throw err;
 var dbo=db.db('user');

 io.on('connection',function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message',function(msg){
   dbo.collection('info').insert({
    "name":msg.name,
    "message":msg.message
   },function(err,res){
    if(err)throw err;
    console.log('inserted');
   });
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function(){
 var socket=io();
 $('form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  socket.emit('chat message',$('#t').val(),$('#m').val());
  $('#m').val('');
  $('#t').val('');
  return false;
 });
 });
</script>
<body>
   <ul id="messages"></ul> 
   <form action="">
    <input id="m" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name"><br>
    <textarea id="t" placeholder="Enter Your Message"></textarea><br>
    <button>send</button>
   </form>
</body>
<style type="text/css">
 #messages, textarea{
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 #m{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
</style>
</html>
```

Comment: Usually it should be function(err, msg). Did you try to print what you're getting in msg.name & msg.message before the .insert() operation?

Comment: no I did not try to print.